# Is clean formatting a pre-installed Windows 8 system and dual booting Windows and Ubuntu in Legacy worth it?

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, uefi

I have a pre-installed Windows 8 system and I have been trying to get it running with Ubuntu since a long time, but problems keep coming up. I recently got a retail version of Windows 8 from my laptop manufacturer. I need Ubuntu badly. So should I clean format and install both in Legacy or continue trying for UEFI? What are the disadvantages involved?

Comment: I would rather run my non-primary OS as a virtual machine.  I think the dual boot thing is an artifact from days long past when VMWare hadn't yet existed.

Comment: Yup! I did try using Ubuntu as a virtual os through virtuabox but it's performance wasn't upto the mark even with an 8GB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

1. First try to make your dualboot work by following the instructions of [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI). If still not good, try step 2 below.
2. Disable UEFI in your BIOS, then format your hard disk, install Windows. Boot into Windows, via its partitioning tools reduce its partition to 100GB. Then install Ubuntu in the remaining space. You should now have a working dualboot. If any issue, please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info).

Comment: The thing is that I have been trying to make a UEFI boot work since past few weeks, but every now and then, some problem or the other springs up out of nowhere.

Comment: this is why I show you how to create a dualboot without UEFI  (see the end of my answer above).